# I would like to know how to add a 2nd USB charging port to a Lenovo YogaBook with only one USB 2.0 port used for both data and charging?

Tags: usb, laptop, battery

I would like to charge a Lenovo YogaBook laptop while using the data port. This isn't supported by the laptop unless I am wrong. I have followed some tutorials which supposed to work but it didn't.

I have tried adding a USB connection which *does* charge but the batteries get too warm and Windows doesn't show it is charging at all. I am afraid to rely on this strategy.

This is my first attempt at modifying hardware so I know I have bypassed some important steps.

I would appreciate any direction offered.

Comment: A USB 2.0 port doesn't supply much power - you might need a powered USB hub. Does this defeat your purpose in posting this?

Comment: You say, “This is my first attempt at modifying hardware so I know I have bypassed some important steps.” Then you say, “I would appreciate any direction offered.” Don’t do this. How does it normally charge? Via USB C? Then just get a USB C hub. But don’t do anything invasive like hardware mods. Just use a USB C hub and that’s that.

Comment: It might help everyone if you told us which Yoga Book you have (model, etc.)

Comment: If your laptop supports a USB-c dock, that should allow charging and data connections simultaneously. Complex electronic equipment modification for first timers probably isn't a good fit on this site.

Comment: Thanks  for all the responses. Sorry it has taken so long to respond. I'll be more diligent. I have the YB1-X91F Windows 10 version. It has only a single USB 2.0 port. I have two of these and I don't mind experimenting on one of them. I have already attempted a hack which I don't trust.

Comment: I don't think a powered dock will work. I believe that will provide extra power for downstram peripherals only. I want to charge my laptop while using it to access data on peripherals. If there is a different hub I am intersted.